# Disable spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config module for some Spring profile

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager, spring-cloud-aws

Is it possible to disable `spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config` module for some Spring profile ?

I'm looking for a way to disable it while testing locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bootstrap.yml` you can set `aws.secretsmanager.enabled: false` for the profile you want to disable Secrets Manager integration.

Comment: Dzięki wielkie :)