# How to disable aws secrets manager lookup in spring-cloud, only for local profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager

There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003929/2875498, but bootstrap has since been deprecated so linked answers don't answer my question.

I am using following dependency to integrate AWS Secrets Manager in SpringBoot 2.4.4

```
    <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
```

I have following properties file in my project and depending on the environment, values from one of them gets picked up at runtime:

```
application.properties
application-lcl.properties
application-dev.properties
application-prd.properties
```

I have following line in my application.properties

`spring.config.import = optional:aws-secretsmanager:/secret/app/abc/pqr/amq/abc-app-user`

this imports username and password for Active MQ and populates following property value:

```
spring.activemq.user     = ${username}
spring.activemq.password = ${password}
```

I wish to override this behaviour when running locally and run app without Secrets Manager lookup, putting `optional` in the config above is not enough and the app fails with the error below. Is there any property that I can add in my `application-lcl.properties` file that will prevent AWS Secrets Manager lookup and use the user/pass values provided in properties file?

```
14:49:25.648 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.c.ConfigDataLocationResolver - Loading secrets from AWS Secret Manager secret with name: /secret/app/abc/pqr/amq/abc-app-user, optional: true
14:49:25.648 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.c.ConfigDataLocationResolver - Unable to load AWS secret from /secret/app/abc/pqr/amq/abc-app-user. Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7b44b63d: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified., com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@42f22995: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
14:49:25.777 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources$AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7b44b63d: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified., com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@42f22995: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
    at io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources.createPropertySource(AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources.java:87)
    at io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator.locate(AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:47)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:637)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at com.xyz.abc.pqr.Application.main(Application.java:20)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7b44b63d: Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified., com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@42f22995: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:833)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:783)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.doInvoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2625)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.invoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2594)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.invoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2583)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.executeGetSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:1206)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.getSecretValue(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:1177)
    at io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource.readSecretValue(AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource.java:76)
    at io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource.init(AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource.java:60)
    at io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources.createPropertySource(AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources.java:81)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Try to add this on your application-lcl.properties: aws.secretsmanager.enabled=false

Comment: @FelipeBonfante: As mentioned here: https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/discussions/80, `aws.secretsmanager.enabled=false` works iff the secret-name ends with `/`. I have tested and found it to be the case. I do not want to change the secret-name to achieve this.

Comment: Well, these are the classes that are called on start up with autoconfigure. Take a look If excluding then on @SpringBootApplication works. If so, you can remove the on springBootApplication and create a configuration that imports then using conditional annotations. Here is the spring factories for Secrets manager https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories